# Lower case all the table names in a database?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database with about 8 tables that all begin with a capital letter. Any quick way to lowercase them all? Or even one by one... if i try this, `RENAME TABLE Contacts TO contacts` it says `ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'contacts' already exists`

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind - use two renames for each table, i.e.: `RENAME TABLE Contacts TO contacts_` then `RENAME TABLE contacts_ TO contacts` Don't know of a better solution. Anyway, what's the point of this? MySQL doesn't care if you select from contacts, Contacts, CoNTactS, etc.

Comment: What OS, out of curiosity?  *["The case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of database, table, and trigger names."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)*

Comment: @Nikoloff Good thinking, that worked. And im using it with Ruby on Rails, naming matters

Comment: @Nikoloff Move it to an answer and i can accept it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two renames - first to a temp name and then to the lowercased:

```
RENAME TABLE Contacts TO contacts_
```

and then

```
RENAME TABLE contacts_ TO contacts
```

Of course, you should be careful not to try using an already existing table name, but if you initially had tables 'Contacts' and 'contacts_' I'd say you have way more serious problems than the case.

Comment: This might be a good case for a stored procedure that does it in one shot if there are a lot of tables.

Answer (score 0):

By checking this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html), you have to:

```
RENAME TABLE tbl_name TO new_tbl_name
```

> **BUT :** The **new_tbl_name** must **NOT** be used by another table as the name must be **unique**

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for bringing back an old post. But I had problems with this aswell.
I made this function to automate the above. I didn't help in my case, but might help other people. That's why I'm posting it here.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `lowercasetables`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE tempname varchar(255);
    DECLARE backupname varchar(255);
    DECLARE sqlst varchar(5000);
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.TABLES where table_schema = schema();

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN cur1;

    REPEAT
        FETCH cur1 INTO tempname;        
        SET backupname = concat(tempname,'_BACKUP'); 

        SET @sqlst = CONCAT(CONCAT('RENAME TABLE ', tempname), CONCAT(' TO ', backupname));
        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sqlst;
        EXECUTE stmt1;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

        SET @sqlst = CONCAT(CONCAT('RENAME TABLE ', backupname), CONCAT(' TO ', LOWER(tempname)));
        PREPARE stmt2 FROM @sqlst;
        EXECUTE stmt2;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;

    UNTIL done END REPEAT;

    CLOSE cur1;

END
```

Comment: Try to post this as a different question or else modify your question if you dont get any response.